# Is it safe to remove all ACL's on home folder?

Tags: macos, permissions, acl, corruption, administrator

I recently started getting lots of errors when trying to access files in my home folder. It seems that the permissions are corrupted. I realized that sometimes, in the Get Info window for a file, even though it says I have read and write access, it also says I have custom access. Often I can't write to the file in question. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Odd permissions]

I believe that this is because of the ACL's on that file. However, there are countless files like this, and setting the correct permissions on the enclosing folder and pressing "Apply to enclosed items" seems to do nothing. This command should remove all ACL's on the home directory:

```
chmod -RN ~/
```

However, is it safe to run this? Will anything bad happen if the ACL's are removed, especially on **every file**?

**EDIT:** Running `ls -le` on one of the affected files gives this line after the normal info:

```
0: group:everyone deny delete
```

And I just realized that I can't delete the file without an administrator password. I never put this there, either.

Comment: I'd recommend using `ls -le` to view permissions instead of the Finder's Info window. The Finder gives a often gives a simplified-to-the-point-of-inaccuracy view of the permissions, while `ls` will show you what they actually are.

Answer (score -1):

If you boot into Recovery HD, you can reset user permissions. More details are here:
http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/15/repair-user-permissions-in-mac-os-x-lion/

Comment: This may not fix everything, but (unlike `chmod -RN ~/`) it's unlikely to break anything that isn't already broken :-). Also, from the screenshot, it looks like there's more than ACLs messed up, and the Recovery mode reset can fix some other problems as well.

Comment: I already tried doing that, and it didn't work. I also tried selecting apply to enclosed items on my home folder after doing that, to no avail. Anyways, the question was is it safe to run that command.